# SQL Server: Gap / Island, 365 day "contiguous" block

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that looks like this:-

**tblMeterReadings**

> id  meter        date        total
>   1      1      03/01/2014  100.1
>   1      1      04/01/2014  184.1
>   1      1      05/01/2014  134.1
>   1      1      06/01/2014  132.1
>   1      1      07/01/2014  126.1
>   1      1      08/01/2014  190.1

This is an 8 day "contiguous block" from `'2014-01-03' to '2014-01-08'`.

In the real table there are "contiguous blocks" of years in length.

I need to select the **MOST RESCENT CONTINUOUS 365 DAY BLOCK** (filtered by meter column).  If 365 cannot be found, then it should select next largest continuous block.

When I say **CONTINUOUS** I mean there must be no days missing.

This is beyond me, so if someone can solve... I will be very impressed.

Comment: could you show what expected result is, and maybe what you tried

Comment: I have no query I have tried... as I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The expected result is the most rescent 365 day continuous block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using distinct to not count days with 2 sets of data

```
declare @gapdays int = 2 -- replace this with 365 in your case

;with x as
(
  select datediff(d, '2014-01-01', [date])-dense_rank()over(order by [date])  grp
         ,[date]
  from @t
)
select top 1 max([date]) last_date, min([date]) first_date, count(distinct [date]) days_in_a_row
from x
group by grp
having count(distinct [date]) >= @gapdays
order by max([date]) desc
```

Comment: The dates don't necessarily start on the 1-Jan-2014... what relevance does that date have in your query?

Comment: @benscammell it has no relevance for my query, you can actually put anything there, It was just to keep the numbers low in the debugging.

Comment: Actually... I've tested further and I'm not sure.

Comment: @benscammell how can you not be sure, this is the best method

Comment: I'm trying to integrate another query (that unions two tables to get the source data for this query)... I can't post the query in here (it's too long).  Is there a way I can contact you? It would really help me...

Comment: I've posted a new question... please would be so kind as to take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482000/ms-sql-help-integrating-two-chunks-of-sql

Answer (score 0):

With recursive `CTE` and `datepart(dayofyear, date)`:

```
with cte as
(
  select id, meter, date, datepart(dayofyear, date) as x, cast(1 as int) as level, t1.date as startDate from tblMeterReadings t1
    where meter = 1 
      and not exists(select * from tblMeterReadings t2 where (datepart(dayofyear, t1.date) - 1) = datepart(dayofyear, t2.date))
  union all
  select t1.id, t1.meter, t1.date, datepart(dayofyear, t1.date) as x, t2.level + 1, t2.startDate from tblMeterReadings t1
   inner join cte t2 ON (datepart(dayofyear, t1.date)) = (datepart(dayofyear, t2.date) + 1)      
)    
select TOP 365 * from cte
where cte.startDate = (select top 1 startdate 
                       from cte 
                       --where Level <= 365 
                       order by Level desc, startDate desc)
order by Level desc
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 365 )
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/420b8/1)

Comment: Thank you... Does this select the most rescent contiguous block?  If so how do you make it get the most rescent 365 day block?

Comment: @benscammell you want longest days sequence in `2014` ?

Comment: No there are many years of data in the DB... I want the most rescent 365 day block.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @benscammell you don't want to mix years ? Example (31/12/2013 and 01/01/2014) will break sequence ?

Comment: No that doesn't break sequence.

Comment: I updated query. It returns longest sequence in table up to 365 rows from descending.

Comment: It need to return the most rescent 365 day block... not the longest block. Is that possible please?

Comment: This fails with "maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted"

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
declare @tblMeterReadings table (id int, meter int, [date] date, total money)

insert into @tblMeterReadings ( id, meter, date, total )
values
    (1, 1, '03/01/2014', 100.1),
    (1, 1, '04/01/2014', 184.1),
    (1, 1, '05/01/2014', 134.1),
    (1, 1, '06/01/2014', 132.1),
    (1, 1, '07/01/2014', 126.1),
    (1, 1, '08/01/2014', 190.1),
    (1, 1, '10/01/2014', 200.1),
    (1, 1, '12/01/2014', 202.1),
    (1, 1, '13/01/2014', 204.1)

;with data as (
    select i = datediff(day, '2014', [date]), * 
    from @tblMeterReadings l
)
, islands as (
    select island = l.i - row_number() over (order by i), l.*
    from data l 
)
, spans as (
    select l = min(i), r = max(i)
    from islands i
    group by island
)
select * 
from spans s
left join data l on s.l = l.i
left join data r on s.r = r.i
```

Most recent continuous block not exceeding 365 days in length will be as follows:

```
select top 1 *
from spans s
left join data l on s.l = l.i
left join data r on s.r = r.i
where s.l - s.r < 365
order by s.l - s.r desc, s.r desc
```

Comment: Thank you... The dates don't necessarily start on the 1-Jan-2014... what relevance does the 2014 have in your query?

Comment: @benscammell `'2014'` is for enumeration and aesthetic purposes only, you can put `0` there if you want. Won't change a thing though.

Comment: I can't make this work... it seems to only return one row, when where are 450 continuous days in the DB.

Comment: @benscammell according to your question the result set should be empty

Comment: The data set I'm using has more than 365 continuous rows.